# Android - setResult não reconhecido

Tags: android

Olá,

Tenho uma tela com uma listagem de "Perfis". Quando clico em um desses perfis vai para o cadastro onde posso atualizar ou excluir esse perfil. Quando eu atualizo o perfil e volto para a tela de listagem o onActivityResult dispara normalmente, porém quando eu apago o perfil o onActivityResult não dispara. A diferença de um método para o outro é que no "apagar" eu primeiro crio um Dialog para que o usuário confirme, clicando em "Sim" ele apagar o perfil, faço o setResult e depois o finish, mas como dito antes, não entra no onActivityResult da tela anterior.

Segue implementação:

Tela - ListaPerfilActivity

```
public class ListaPerfilActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

private Toolbar mToolbar;
private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
private ArrayList<Perfil_PER> listaPerfil;
private PerfilAdapter perfilAdapter;
private FloatingActionButton fab;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista_perfil);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.tb_main);

    atualizarLista();

    fab = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.setOnClickListener(this);
}

private static final int ACT_CADASTRO = 1;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.fab:
            Intent it = new Intent(this, PerfilActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(it, ACT_CADASTRO);
            break;
    }
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int codigo, int resultado, Intent it) {
    if (codigo == ACT_CADASTRO) {
        if (resultado == RESULT_OK) {
            atualizarLista();
        }
    }
}

public void atualizarLista() {
    RepositorioPerfilScript repositorioPerfilScript = new RepositorioPerfilScript(this);
    listaPerfil = repositorioPerfilScript.listarPerfis();

    perfilAdapter = new PerfilAdapter(this, listaPerfil);

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rv_list);
    mRecyclerView.setAdapter(perfilAdapter);
    mRecyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
}}
```

Tela - PerfilActivity

```
public class PerfilActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener, View.OnClickListener {
ArrayList<Icones> listaIcones;

private EditText Nome;
private EditText Jogador;
private EditText Cronica;
private EditText Natureza;
private EditText Comportamento;
private EditText Cla;
private EditText Geracao;
private EditText Refugio;
private EditText Conceito;
ImageView imageView;
int selecionado;

Spinner spinner;

private long codigo;
private boolean inicio;

private MaterialDialog materialDialog;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_perfil);

    inicio = false;

    FloatingActionMenu fab = (FloatingActionMenu) findViewById(R.id.fab);
    fab.showMenuButton(true);
    fab.setClosedOnTouchOutside(true);

    FloatingActionButton fab1 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab1);
    FloatingActionButton fab2 = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.fab2);

    fab1.setOnClickListener(this);
    fab2.setOnClickListener(this);

    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    listaIcones = new ArrayList<>();
    listaIcones.add(new Icones(R.drawable.icon_01));
    listaIcones.add(new Icones(R.drawable.icon_02));
    listaIcones.add(new Icones(R.drawable.icon_03));
    listaIcones.add(new Icones(R.drawable.icon_04));
    listaIcones.add(new Icones(R.drawable.icon_05));
    listaIcones.add(new Icones(R.drawable.icon_06));
    listaIcones.add(new Icones(R.drawable.icon_07));
    listaIcones.add(new Icones(R.drawable.icon_08));
    listaIcones.add(new Icones(R.drawable.icon_09));
    listaIcones.add(new Icones(R.drawable.icon_10));

    spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spImage);
    SpinnerIconePerfilAdapter spinnerIconePerfilAdapter = new SpinnerIconePerfilAdapter(this, R.layout.spinner_icone_perfil, listaIcones);
    spinner.setAdapter(spinnerIconePerfilAdapter);
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

    ValidateUtil vu = new ValidateUtil();

    Nome = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edNome);
    Jogador = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edJogador);
    Cronica = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edCronica);
    Natureza = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edNatureza);
    Comportamento = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edComportamento);
    Cla = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edCla);
    Geracao = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edGeracao);
    Refugio = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edRefugio);
    Conceito = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edConceito);

    Nome.addTextChangedListener(vu);
    Jogador.addTextChangedListener(vu);
    Cronica.addTextChangedListener(vu);
    Natureza.addTextChangedListener(vu);
    Comportamento.addTextChangedListener(vu);
    Cla.addTextChangedListener(vu);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);

    Intent it = getIntent();
    if (it != null) {
        inicio = true;
        Bundle params = it.getExtras();
        if (params != null) {
            codigo = params.getLong("codigo_perfil");
            String msg = "Codigo: " + codigo;
            Toast.makeText(this, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            preencheCampos();
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
    //spinner.setIn
    if (!inicio) {
        imageView.setImageResource(listaIcones.get(position).getImageId());
        selecionado = position;
    }
    inicio = false;
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    String aux = "";

    switch( v.getId() ){
        case R.id.fab1:
            salvarPerfil();
            //TODO: Deve encaminhar para ficha
            break;
        case R.id.fab2:
            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
            builder.setTitle("Apagar Perfil");
            builder.setMessage("Deseja cancelar o perfil?");
            builder.setCancelable(true);
            builder.setPositiveButton("Sim", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    apagarPerfil();
                }
            });

            builder.setNegativeButton("Não", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                }
            });
            AlertDialog dialog = builder.create();
            dialog.show();
            break;
    }

}

private void salvarPerfil() {
    Perfil_PER perfil;
    RepositorioPerfilScript repositorioPerfilScript = new RepositorioPerfilScript(this);

    if (codigo == 0) {
        perfil = new Perfil_PER();

        perfil.setPER_NOME(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edNome)).getText().toString());
        perfil.setPER_JOGADOR(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edJogador)).getText().toString());
        perfil.setPER_CRONICA(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edCronica)).getText().toString());
        perfil.setPER_NATUREZA(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edNatureza)).getText().toString());
        perfil.setPER_COMPORTAMENTO(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edComportamento)).getText().toString());
        perfil.setPER_CLA(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edCla)).getText().toString());
        perfil.setPER_GERACAO(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edGeracao)).getText().toString());
        perfil.setPER_REFUGIO(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edRefugio)).getText().toString());
        perfil.setPER_CONCEITO(((EditText) findViewById(R.id.edConceito)).getText().toString());
        perfil.setPER_DATA_CADASTRO(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());

        perfil.setPER_PHOTO(listaIcones.get(selecionado).getImageId());
    } else {
        perfil = repositorioPerfilScript.buscarPerfil(codigo);
    }

    if (validateFields(perfil)) {
        repositorioPerfilScript.salvar(perfil);
        setResult(RESULT_OK);
        finish();
    }
}

private void apagarPerfil() {
    RepositorioPerfilScript repositorioPerfilScript = new RepositorioPerfilScript(this);
    repositorioPerfilScript.deletar(codigo);

    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();

}

private boolean validateFields(Perfil_PER perfil) {
    if (TextUtils.isEmpty(perfil.getPER_NOME())) {
        Nome.requestFocus();
        Nome.setError("Nome é obrigatório!");
        //Nome.setError(resources.getString(R.string.login_user_required)); - Precisa criar no arquivo de Strings
        return false;
    } else if (!(perfil.getPER_NOME().length() > 3)) {
        Nome.requestFocus();
        Nome.setError("Nome deve ter mais que 3 letras!");
        //Nome.setError(resources.getString(R.string.login_user_required)); - Precisa criar no arquivo de Strings
        return false;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(perfil.getPER_JOGADOR())) {
        Jogador.requestFocus();
        Jogador.setError("Jogador é obrigatório!");
        //Jogador.setError(resources.getString(R.string.login_user_required)); - Precisa criar no arquivo de Strings
        return false;
    } else if (!(perfil.getPER_JOGADOR().length() > 3)) {
        Jogador.requestFocus();
        Jogador.setError("Jogador deve ter mais que 3 letras!");
        //Jogador.setError(resources.getString(R.string.login_user_required)); - Precisa criar no arquivo de Strings
        return false;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(perfil.getPER_CRONICA())) {
        Cronica.requestFocus();
        Cronica.setError("Crônica é obrigatório!");
        //Jogador.setError(resources.getString(R.string.login_user_required)); - Precisa criar no arquivo de Strings
        return false;
    } else if (!(perfil.getPER_CRONICA().length() > 3)) {
        Cronica.requestFocus();
        Cronica.setError("Crônica deve ter mais que 3 letras!");
        //Jogador.setError(resources.getString(R.string.login_user_required)); - Precisa criar no arquivo de Strings
        return false;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(perfil.getPER_NATUREZA())) {
        Natureza.requestFocus();
        Natureza.setError("Natureza é obrigatório!");
        //Jogador.setError(resources.getString(R.string.login_user_required)); - Precisa criar no arquivo de Strings
        return false;
    } else if (!(perfil.getPER_NATUREZA().length() > 3)) {
        Natureza.requestFocus();
        Natureza.setError("Natureza deve ter mais que 3 letras!");
        //Jogador.setError(resources.getString(R.string.login_user_required)); - Precisa criar no arquivo de Strings
        return false;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(perfil.getPER_COMPORTAMENTO())) {
        Comportamento.requestFocus();
        Comportamento.setError("Comportamento é obrigatório!");
        //Jogador.setError(resources.getString(R.string.login_user_required)); - Precisa criar no arquivo de Strings
        return false;
    } else if (!(perfil.getPER_COMPORTAMENTO().length() > 3)) {
        Comportamento.requestFocus();
        Comportamento.setError("Comportamento deve ter mais que 3 letras!");
        //Jogador.setError(resources.getString(R.string.login_user_required)); - Precisa criar no arquivo de Strings
        return false;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(perfil.getPER_CLA())) {
        Cla.requestFocus();
        Cla.setError("Clã é obrigatório!");
        //Jogador.setError(resources.getString(R.string.login_user_required)); - Precisa criar no arquivo de Strings
        return false;
    } else if (!(perfil.getPER_CLA().length() > 3)) {
        Cla.requestFocus();
        Cla.setError("Clã deve ter mais que 3 letras!");
        //Jogador.setError(resources.getString(R.string.login_user_required)); - Precisa criar no arquivo de Strings
        return false;
    } else if (TextUtils.isEmpty(perfil.getPER_GERACAO())) {
        Geracao.requestFocus();
        Geracao.setError("Geração é obrigatório!");
        //Jogador.setError(resources.getString(R.string.login_user_required)); - Precisa criar no arquivo de Strings
        return false;
    } else if (!(perfil.getPER_GERACAO().length() > 3)) {
        Geracao.requestFocus();
        Geracao.setError("Geração deve ter mais que 3 letras!");
        //Jogador.setError(resources.getString(R.string.login_user_required)); - Precisa criar no arquivo de Strings
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

private void preencheCampos() {
    RepositorioPerfilScript repositorioPerfilScript = new RepositorioPerfilScript(this);
    Perfil_PER perfil = repositorioPerfilScript.buscarPerfil(codigo);

    if (perfil != null) {
        //Nome
        Nome.setText(perfil.getPER_NOME());
        //Jogador
        Jogador.setText(perfil.getPER_JOGADOR());
        //Cronica
        Cronica.setText(perfil.getPER_CRONICA());
        //Natureza
        Natureza.setText(perfil.getPER_NATUREZA());
        //Comportamento
        Comportamento.setText(perfil.getPER_COMPORTAMENTO());
        //Cla
        Cla.setText(perfil.getPER_CLA());
        //Geracao
        Geracao.setText(perfil.getPER_GERACAO());
        //Refugio
        Refugio.setText(perfil.getPER_REFUGIO());
        //Conceito
        Conceito.setText(perfil.getPER_CONCEITO());
        //Photo -  imageView.setImageResource(listaIcones.get(position).getImageId());
        imageView.setImageResource(perfil.getPER_PHOTO());
    }

}}
```

Alguém saberia informar como corrigir tal problema?

Comment: Já verificou que não entra mesmo no `onActivityResult()`? Se não verificou, outra possibilidade é que `repositorioPerfilScript.deletar(codigo)` não efectuou nenhuma mudança na lista de perfis, não é?

Comment: Olá Dan. Sim, verifiquei o onActivityResult(). Quando uso o método salvar ele registra as mudanças, encerra a activity e atualiza a lista na tela anterior. No apagar, ele registra a exclusão do registro normalmente, encerra a activity porém não dispara o método para atualizar a lista(ou seja, não entra no onActivityResult()). Tanto que se eu sair da aplicação e entrar novamente a lista vem atualizada(com o registro excluído). Como no onClick do apagar eu entro em um Dialog que implementa um outro onClick, ele se perde em algum lugar e não retorna para a activity anterior.

Comment: Muito estranho. Não tem nada de errado, deveria funcionar. Já experimentou tirar o dialog e chamar o apagar perfil diretamente pra ver se o resultado é o mesmo?

Comment: Olá @RodrigoHenriques, ainda não fiz esse teste, mas acredito que irá funcionar, porém preciso do Dialog para que o usuário não apague o perfil por acidente.

Comment: Faz esse teste e conta pra gente o resultado.

Comment: Olá @RodrigoHenriques. Consegui resolver de outra maneira. Coloquei a atualização dos dados da tela no onResume(), assim não preciso mandar uma resposta(setResult()). Dessa forma os dados são atualizados independente de qual operação eu tenha feita na tela de CRUD. Obrigado pela atenção.

Comment: Não há de quê. Fico feliz que tenha resolvido. Abraço.